# How to generate half-daily logs using log4j2?

Tags: log4j2

I want to generate half-daily log files through log4j2 configuration. I have given :

```
<RollingFile name="fileAppender" filename ="${logName} append="true" 
    FilePattern="${logName}. %d{yyyy-MM-dd-a}">
```

And also defined:

```
<Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" 
        Module="true"/>
```

But i am getting only AM log in this way though i want it to be something :

```
a.log.2016-03-23-AM
b.log.2016-03-23-PM
```

Can somebody help me out in the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CronTriggeringPolicy for this. I borrowed the expression from the answer at [Cron Expression (Quartz) for a program to run every midnight at 12 am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131999/cron-expression-quartz-for-a-program-to-run-every-midnight-at-12-am) for the actual expression to use.

```
<RollingFile name="fileAppender" filename ="${logName} append="true" FilePattern="${logName}.$$d{yyyy-MM-dd-a}">
    <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0,12 * * ?" />
</RollingFile>
```

Comment: In the link you only find the normal CronExpression. For log4j CronExpression see [CronExpression(Apache)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.7/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/CronExpression.html). Difference here is that in Apache there are seconds as well.